# Solr language detection update processor for denormalized mixed-language documents

Tags: solr, language-detection

I have a database of things, with each thing being able to have several names in different languages. This is currently normalized to a *thing has-many names* schema:

```
things
------
id
...

names
-----
id
thing_id
language
name
```

I am indexing this using Solr and am trying to figure out the best way to denormalize this into a Lucene schema. This one works okay:

```
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="uuid" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    ...
    <field name="name_eng" type="text_eng" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="name_jpn" type="text_cjk" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="name_kor" type="text_cjk" indexed="true" stored="true" />
</fields>
```

The problem is that I need to specify a field and field type for each supported language individually, and there may be a lot. Since I also use the SQL DataImportHandler, it means I have to duplicate a lot of code to specify SQL queries to import these from the database into this schema. Further, the `language` field of the names is not always correct since it's based on user input.

I was looking at the [language detection capabilities](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection) Solr offers, which look very good. But they only seem to work on documents as a whole, which in this case won't help a lot I guess. Is there a way to specify a single `multiValued` field in the schema in which I can store names, whose language will be automatically detected and indexed accordingly? Or other ways in which the language detection facilities could make my life easier here?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a transformer that would do that on the index side, but the query side would not get the same analysis chain, so that wouldn't work.

What does the text for these "things" look like?

If it is less than about 200 characters, language ID will not work very well. Think of it as "language guessing", with a statistical approach. With small amounts of data, guesses are bad. Is "mobile" English or Danish? Both, really. "Die" is English and German, and so on. For a good guess, a thousand characters would be helpful.

Does the text have trademarked names? "LaserJet" and "Linux" are the same in all languages and rarely inflected, so linguistic processing just doesn't do anything. Maybe you can get by without language-specific stemming.

Finally, you might consider n-grams instead of linguistic processing. It is a completely different model from language-sensitive matching, but it might work better for this. In a sense, it is doing the same sort of statistical pattern matching as language ID, but at query time instead of at index time. It will take short sequences of patterns from the query and look for those in the text. It takes more time and space, but it is worth a try.